# CSS Styling mistake?

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem styling my links.

There is a div with an id **kofa** which contains basically everything.

There is a div with class **post-date** in which there's a link (a).

All the links in **kofa** work as they should, but the link in **post-date** just seems to take the styling of **kofa**'s links and not the style specified in the file:

```
#kofa a, #kofa a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #a00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#kofa a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #bb0000;
}

.post-date a, .post-date a:visited {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: planewalker;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Show the HTML .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because kofa is assigned as ID, and post-date is "only" an class. To avoid this, you should either set an !important behind every css declaration in .post-date OR define inline-style OR define .post-date also as an ID.

```
.post-date a, .post-date a:visited {
  padding-left: 50px!important;
  font-family: planewalker!important;
  color: #eee!important;
  font-size: 14px!important;
}
```

Comment: putting important is a bad practice. If you really want to solve the problem use class name instead of id . It means use class name for both.

Comment: Cascading Styles would make more sense than `!important`

Comment: avoid using important because it overrules the hierarchy of importance. Use it only as a last resort. I would even say that only use it if you are using the css you didnt not write and don't want to mess with. Otherwise, understand that id level counts 10x more than a class level. An the one with a higher level wins. So to avoid using importance, just add the id at the begining of each css declaration like: #kofa .post-date a, #kofa .post-date a:visited { .....

Answer (score 3):

Your need to add `#kofa` before `.post-date` (**see snippet below**), it's important how the inheritance is used to **override** styles.

**Note:** Avoid `!important` when possible.

```css
#kofa a, #kofa a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #a00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#kofa a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #bb0000;
}

#kofa .post-date a, 
#kofa .post-date a:visited {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: planewalker;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kofa">
  <a> Kofa link </a>
  
  <div class="post-date">
    <a> post link </a>
  </div>

  <a class="post-date">
    wrong way
  </a>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use that styles to be applied to `a` that contains the class `post-date`

```
<a class="post-date">
    on tag
</a>
```

```css
#kofa a, #kofa a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #a00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#kofa a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #bb0000;
}

#kofa a.post-date, 
#kofa a.post-date:visited {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: planewalker;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kofa">
  <a> Kofa link </a>
  
  <a class="post-date">
    applied on a class
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The class is on the div and not the link, so that wasn't the problem, but as Nilse explained, I needed a "!important". Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov Sometimes, using `!important` can cause problems in other places, see my corrected snnipet. You need to add `#kofa` before `.post-date`

Comment: I was just in the middle of typing this as my answer when you updated it.  Introducing `!important` leads to more and more `!important` additions throughout your CSS.  if you structure it correctly like in your updated example it works better and more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your HTML structure. But hope this code help you .

```css
 .first a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #a00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.first a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #bb0000;
}

.post-date a, .post-date a:visited {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: planewalker;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="kofa">
     <div class="first">
      <a href="">Hello</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-date">
      <a href="">Post date</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looking at the code snippet you ran, the margins, font sizes and colours are not applied correctly.

Comment: If CSS is not working for post-date link then you can use important in css like color: #eee!important

Comment: Vubon, its considered bad practice to use `!important` as you then need to implement it again and again when overriding your styles. @Adricadars solution is the better structured one http://stackoverflow.com/a/42508413/2208

Comment: All right . If you don't want to use !important then you can need to some change of your HTML code . You can add a new class for first link like post-date class . then delete your kofa id form css . Now no CSS override your post-data css . Check now the code . you can go ahead like this way

Answer (score 0):

id is worth 10 points and class is worth 1point. To determine who wins, the points add up. So to make sure that the class wins, just put the id declaration in front of it.

```
#kofa a, #kofa a:visited {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #a00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#kofa a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #bb0000;
}

#kofa .post-date a, #kofa .post-date a:visited {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: planewalker;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```